# Why Azure AKS Service IP address is not accessible

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am working with aks service. Started with a tutorial on Azure that deploys Azure Voting app.
Then I created my app. It is a Restful service. created a container image. Now when I deploy my service, the public service end point is not accessible. Not only the app does not respond, traceroute command take me to msdn network but not to the ip address, neither is it pingable.
Here is the tutorial URL from which I took the sample for the front end deployment and service yaml and works fine.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough-portal

Here is my yaml. What am I doing wrong.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bwce-simplerest
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bwce-simplerest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bwce-simplerest
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bwce-simplerest
        image: tauqirghani/simplerest:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7070
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bwce-simplerest
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: "TCP"
    targetPort: 7070
  selector:
    app: bwce-simplerest
```

Comment: can you verify endpoints are getting created for that service? `kubectl get endpoints`? they should match pods ip addresses

Comment: kubectl get endpoints
bwce-simplerest    10.244.0.7:7070     2m
kubernetes            172.31.36.203:443   32m

Comment: This does not display very well - but yes my service has an ip address that is most likely correct. It takes a few steps to go into the cluster to verify but 10.244.0.7 looks like correct ip of the pod running the service.

Comment: Thanks very much. Not sure how but just checked the public IP and it responds. I bet I have not changed the yaml file.